# STDIN in python

Tags: python, stdin

I study python and I have task difficult for me.

Task:
Input 2 string:
5
2 3 9 2 9

Sample Output:
2 2 3 9 9

I know how to sort it, but I have trouble with input. Test-case input used stdin. I write this:

```
import sys

input = sys.stdin.read()
tokens = input.split()

n = int(tokens[0])

A = tokens[1:len(tokens)]
B = []

M = 10

for i in range(M):
  B.append(0)

for j in range(n):
  B[int(A[j])] = B[int(A[j])] + 1

k = 0
for i in range(M):
  for j in range(B[i]):
    A[k] = i
      k = k + 1

print(A)
```

and get error "out range" for 
    B[int(A[j])] = B[int(A[j])] + 1

Comment: What is the 5 for? (in the input)

Comment: It is count of array's elements

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
input = sys.stdin.read()
tokens = input.split()

n = int(tokens[0])

A = tokens[1:len(tokens)]
B = []
```

Use the following code

```
input_n = sys.stdin.readline()
n = int(input_n)
input_tokens = sys.stdin.readline()
tokens = input_tokens.split()

A = tokens[0:len(tokens)]
B = []
```

You are inputting n and tokens on separate lines. So call sys.stdin.readline() twice